# Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException: 'Permission denied'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ssh, sftp

I am new to SFTP.

I am getting `Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException: 'Permission denied'` error while uploading an image to the SFTP location from asp.net core.

I have installed the WinSCP tool, and there I can see that particular SFTP folder doesn't have "write" permission. and I don't have the right to change the permission.

below is my code

```
public void UploadFileToSFTP(IFormFile requestFile)
{
    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
    {
       sftp.Connect();
                
        if (sftp.IsConnected)
        {                  
           using (var uplfileStream = requestFile.OpenReadStream()) 
           {
              sftp.UploadFile(uplfileStream, "/folderpath/" + requestFile.fileName, null);
           }
        }
        sftp.Disconnect();
   }        
}
```

am I doing anything wrong in the code?

or just adding write permission to the folder will work here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So can you upload the file to that folder using WinSCP? If you can, please post WinSCP log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  I am not able to upload from WinSCP as well getting this error -> Cannot create remote file,Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server (en): Permission denied

Comment: If you cannot upload the file using a GUI SFTP client, you do not have a programming question. Fix your permission problem first. Talk to your server administrator (preferred). Or ask at [su].

Comment: Do you have write permission to any folder?  You may need to specify a different folder location to upload.  With FTP your login is assigned a default folder and if it isn't set correctly you will get errors.  Changing the folder or getting the default folder changed will solve issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to upload images to the SFTP server after getting "**write**" permission for the SFTP folder.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help someone.

I got the same error but I was able to upload files through WinSCP to the same folder.
My issue was that I didn't include '/' before the folder name

So instead of this:

```
sftpClient.UploadFile(memoryStream, "MyFolder/MyFile.txt");
```

Do this:

```
sftpClient.UploadFile(memoryStream, "/MyFolder/MyFile.txt");
```